# Failed to launch Jenkins agents via SSH

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I've set up a Jenkins master (user:`jenkins`) and a Jenkins slave (user: `jenkinslave`).

I established an SSH connection between them, and I'm able to SSH from master to slave. I configured the slave node, gave the remote root directory (`/var/lib/jenkinslave`) and launched it using *"Launch slaves using SSH"* method. But the slave is offline; I've tried all the host verification strategies, but I'm still getting:

> [SSH] Authentication failed.

I'm able to establish the SSH connection, but the authentication is failing. I've provided the `jenkinslave` credentials and they're correct.

Manually trusted key strategy:

```
[09/29/17 16:51:17] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to ip-10-0-2-218.ap-south-1.compute.internal:22.
[09/29/17 16:51:17] [SSH] SSH host key matches key seen previously for this host. Connection will be allowed.
[09/29/17 16:51:17] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[09/29/17 16:51:17] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[09/29/17 16:51:17] [SSH] Connection closed
```

Host key strategy:

```
[09/29/17 16:53:40] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to ip-10-0-2-218.ap-south-1.compute.internal:22.
[09/29/17 16:53:41] [SSH] SSH host key matches key in Known Hosts file. Connection will be allowed.
[09/29/17 16:53:41] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[09/29/17 16:53:41] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[09/29/17 16:53:41] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

I've read a few articles where they suggested to use a manual key, which I did above, and still the authentication failed.
What am I missing out here?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same problem. I tried many things, but it did not work. I gave up using ssh to connect and I chose "Launch agent via command execution in master"

```
ssh -i PATH_TO_KEY_WITHOUT_PASSPHRASE USER @ HOST "cd AGENT_HOME_DIR && curl -O http: //JENKINS_URL/jnlpJars/slave.jar && java -jar slave.jar"
```

This worked perfectly.

See *[Run SSH Agent using a command on Master](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/234491548-Run-SSH-Agent-using-a-command-on-Master)*.

Comment: After some wasted hours trying to fix Jenkins SSH connection, this option saved our day. Thanks!

Comment: can you guys help me with my setup, I'm also following same reference link but no dice. Mine just keeps on spinning when launching, no error displayed in log          ssh -i /jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa jenkins@XXX.XX.XXX.XXX "cd /var/lib/jenkins && curl -O http://localhost:9091/jnlpJars/agent.jar && java -jar agent.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your ssh key in ~jenkins/.ssh on the master? Try the following:

ln -s ~jenkins/.ssh ~jenkins/ssh

It's irrational to me too, but it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use "username with password" credential type, not "SSH Username with private key" :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).